# How to specify a repository for a dependency in Maven

Tags: maven-2, dependencies

In projects with several dependencies and repositories, the try-and-error approach of Maven for downloading dependencies is a bit cumbersome and slow, so I was wondering if there is any way to set an specific repo for some declared dependencies.

For example, I want for bouncycastle to check directly BouncyCastle's Maven repo at http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/ instead of official Maven.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Not possible. Maven checks the repositories in their declaration order until a given artifact gets resolved (or not).

Some repository manager can do something approaching this though. For example, Nexus has a [routes](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-managing-routes.html) feature that does something equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I was sure it wasn't possible but I wanted to know from other Maven users. I just reduced the defined repos and created a local one.

Comment: This would be a good addition to Maven, and I have asked for it. It would enable Maven to work in the github world.

Comment: As of January 2019, this is now possible in Gradle (although I've not tried it yet). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465569

Comment: Gradle has [exclusiveContent](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#declaring_content_exclusively_found_in_one_repository) allow retrieval dep from a single  repository

Answer (score 30):

I have moved libraries from 3rd party repositories to their own project and included this project as first module in my base project:

*base/pom.xml*

```
...
<modules>
    <module>thirdparty</module>
    <module>mymodule</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

*base/thirdparty/pom.xml:*

```
...
<artifactId>thirdparty</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>First thirdparty repository</id>
        <url>https://...</url>
    </repository>
    ...
</repositories> 

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <!-- Dependency from the third party repository -->
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

*base/mymodule/pom.xml:*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>thirdparty</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

This will ensure that the libraries from the thirdparty repository are downloaded into the local repository as soon as the root project is build. For all other dependencies the repositories are not visible and therefore not included when downloading.

Answer (score -1):

This post could be very old but might be useful to someone. I specified the two repositories in pom.xml like below and it worked.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>http://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Default</id>
            <name>All apart from Aspose</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: This is not the solution, this way Maven will always try to download every dependency from both repositories.