# Gradle: specify appropriate repo for dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have several repos and a lot of dependencies.
It looks like this in build.gradle:

```java
repositories {
    maven {url "A"}
    maven {url "B"}
}


dependencies {
    compile 'libA'
    compile 'libB'
    compile 'libC'
}
```

Is there is a way to specify that I will download libA from one repo (A) and libB and libC from another repo (B)?

Comment: why do you need to do this? does libA also exist in repoB and libB/libC exist in repoA but different versions that you don't want to resolve to? I don't believe gradle supports user provided latest or conflict strategies so you might be stuck.

Comment: Could this become relevant now after gradle 4.3? See https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/release-notes.html#avoid-checking-other-repositories-when-dependency-resolution-in-one-repository-fails

Comment: To answer @Matt, this is usually done when importing software from proprietary vendors. If they just put their code in Maven or the usual place, we wouldn't have to configure this stuff...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to associate a dependency with a repository. The repositories will always be searched in their declared order.

Comment: if in the example above, both maven repos contain a 'libZ', does that mean that libA will be drawn from maven repo A?

Comment: If a matching version is found, yes.

Comment: This answer is outdated and should not be accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465569/4651874

Answer (score 64):

As of Jan 2019 this is possible. Say you have a specific repository for Oracle dependencies:

```java
maven {
    url 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/somepath/oracle-binaries/'
    content {
        includeGroupByRegex "com\\.oracle.*"
    }
 }
```

Note: this requires at least Gradle 5.1

See also:

- [Declaring Repositories > Repository content filtering - Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-content-filtering)
- [Gradle 5.1 release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/release-notes.html#repository-to-dependency-matching)

Comment: In addition to `includeGroupByRegex`, there are also:
`includeGroup`, `includeModule`, `includeModuleByRegex`, `includeVersion`, `includeVersionByRegex`. (also some exclusion options)