# Gradle: Resolve a given jar from a specified repository

Tags: java, gradle

For a gradle build (java project), I usually specify a set of repositories in which the dependencies are searched.

Is it possible to force gradle to take a given jar from a specified repository? I want to have a local configuration file which says something like "Take foo.jar from the local repository" and my gradle scripts reads this configuration file and does exactly this (while resolving the other dependencies "normally").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying different repo configuration per dependency is currently not possible with Gradle. This has been requested and discussed before. There is an [open and unresolved Jira](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1066) as well. Please also see:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597516/gradle-specify-appropriate-repo-for-dependency) [2](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/force-dependency-to-be-resolved-against-a-specific-set-of-repository/436)

Comment: Gradle migrated from JIRA to Github.  Corresponding issue here:  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1207

Answer (score 1):

Gradle will usually take the first repository it finds the file in, so if you add your local repository as the first item, it will load it from local.

You can read more about resolving of dependencies [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolution).

> Modules from earlier repositories are preferred over modules in later repositories.

You can always just add your dependency as a jar file to the project. In that case there is no further resolution.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that putting the local repository first means that ALL dependencies will be resolved from there, not just the one specified by the config file.

Comment: @JFMeier Indeed. Those which it can not resolve will then be loaded from the next repository in line

Comment: @JFMeier, you can always create a so-called dependency sub-module  and specify custom order of repositories there.