# How to make build with dependencies in multiple private nexus locations faster

Tags: java, gradle, build, nexus

My project depends on several jars each in a different directory in nexus
i.e.

```
jar1 is in repo.company.com/dirX/jar1
jar2 is in repo.company.com/dirY/jar2
jar3 is in repo.company.com/dirZ/jar3
```

for this we have defined 3 seperate private repos

```
repositories{
    maven {url "repo.priv.company.com/dirX"}
    maven {url "repo.priv.company.com/dirY"}
    maven {url "repo.priv.company.com/dirZ"}  
}

dependencies {
    compile(
[GroupX:jar1:Version1.1],
[GroupY:jar2:Version1.11],
[GroupY:jar3:Version1.10]
)
}
```

Problem is this works, but the build is very slow, because Gradle will look for the jars in the order that the repos were defined so by the time it gets to jar3 it will first look in both dirs X and Y which seems to take a long time to timeout

Question:
Is their a way to set a time limit on how long it takes to resolve a dependency for a given repo OR alternately is there a way to explictly specify which repo gradle should look in first for a given dependency ...i.e. tel gradle to start by looking for jar3 in the 3rd private nexus repo rather than the first two.

Comment: Why not set up a virtual repository and let nexus do the heavy lifting? If this is a private nexus installation then it's better to create a single virtual repo that maps all relevant real repos. That way you only ever need to add one repo to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Per dependency repo configuration is currently not possible in Gradle. See [open issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1066). The repos are always searched in the order that they appear.

Also see: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597516/gradle-specify-appropriate-repo-for-dependency) [2](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/force-dependency-to-be-resolved-against-a-specific-set-of-repository/436)

Comment: Is there a way to make the timeout faster?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't really a timeout. The step has to wait for the repo to reply back saying it doesn't have the requested dependency. Does your build get faster after the dependencies are cached in your gradle cache?